# Использование библиотеки boost

Tags: c++

Ребят, пытаюсь разобраться с библиотекой boost. Нужны большие числа. Правильно ли будет, если я буду использовать числа типа cpp_int, и обычный ассоциативный map?
Примерно так:

```
mp::cpp_int num1("12347893489239423480238407238947892349823");
map<mp::cpp_int, mp::cpp_int> vals;
```

Comment: "Правильно ли" для чего?

Comment: Для работы с большими числами, и будет очень много значений

Comment: вроде всё так... что тут может смущать? ведь для `cpp_int` boost определил `operator<`... разве что namespace boost'овский зовётся boost::multiprecision, а не mp, если верить докам, но подозреваю, что это какое-то переопределение...

Comment: корректно ли использовать библиотеку boost, когда надо работать с большими числами и очень много записей хранить. Вот и интересуюсь справиться ли эта библиотека вместе с обычным map

Comment: @Александр, всё зависит от того сколько это «очень много» и что значит «справится». std::map даст правильный результат по вставке/поиску за логарифмическое время на любом содержимом, которое предоставляет корректный `std::less<T>()`. Для больших чисел временные показатели доступа будут не хуже чем для строк, что в 9 случаях из 10 будет приемлемо. Сомневаться в возможностях работы boost'а с большими числами ИМХО излишне, пока не найден баг.